# Where do I see deployment comments besides when I create them on Opsworks?

Tags: deployment, aws-opsworks

I automate deployments via Grunt and I can't see a view where I see the deployment comments even in the list of all deployments per instance.

[image: Deploy App]

Answer (score 1):

We added this feature a few weeks ago. If you go to "Deployments" in your Stack you will see the comments in the fourth column.

I noted the wish to see deployment comments per instance as a feature request.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Great, I sent in that request!